# How to set parent_id=NULL in child table when record in parent table is deleted?

Tags: atk4, php

How to set parent_id=NULL in child table when record in parent table is deleted?

It's like ON DELETE = SET NULL in MySQL INNODB tables, but I would like to avoid using all this (cascading, ignoring, updating and setting null) functionality in INNODB level and move it to atk4 Model to keep all this in logic one place.

For example,

```
class Model_Parent extends Model_Table{
  public $table='parent';
  function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->addField('name');
    $this->hasMany('Child');
    $this->addHook('beforeDelete',$this);
  }
  function beforeDelete($m){
    // I guess here I should somehow set parent_id=NULL in all related Model_Child
    // records, but when I do so, then it's again DB constraint violation of course
    $c = $m->ref('Child');
    foreach($c as $junk){
      $c->set('parent_id',NULL); // this and below is not working
      $c->save();
    }
  }
}

class Model_Child extends Model_Table{
  public $table='child';
  function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->addField('name');
    $this->hasOne('Parent');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, you just need to go into DSQL from Model:

```
$m->ref('Child')->dsql()->set('parent_id',null)->update();
```

More info: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSRaYpoJFHk&list=PL7CBF92AB03A1CA3B&index=3&feature=plpp_video

Comment: This works as expected.
Strangely it looks quite the same as I did before (with foreach loop and save() method), but this works and save() don't.
Anyway, this is the post which gives real answer to question above, so I'll accept it. Other posts and comments above are useful too - check them out.

Comment: Your solution loads every entry individually which will be quite a hammering of SQL. The use of dsql() is much more faster.  Can I ask you to try this in your own example `$c->set('parent_id', $c->dsql()->expr('null'));`, - I'm just curious if it would fix it.

Comment: The bug with "null" is now fixed and you can write `$c->set('parent_id',null);` again.

Comment: Thanks Romans and sorry for not testing expression mentioned in your previous comment. I somehow missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to re-invent the wheel by doing a typical database task in your code.

If you don't want the database to manage the foreign key relations, you shouldn't use those relations. In that case you can set your columns to `NULL` or any other value. But no one could prove the consistency of your database.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but what's driving me crazy is when you have let's say 50 or even more tables in larger project and all these on delete and on update settings are set in DB level, then it's hard to switch back and forth from DB admin panel and ATK4 Models again and again.
It's very easy to make mistakes if all this logic is split in two places - in DB level and in ATK4 models.

Comment: I've accidentally deleted some chunks of the database especially when I mixed up "join" with "leftJoin". Cascading deletes are dangerous.

Comment: I can only agree with you about cascading deletes. I guess I should give soft delete functionality a try in my project (at least in future versions).

Comment: I'll also give +1 to answer above because it's good and correct even if not directly answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if parent_id column permits NULL values.